# Joining two dataframes by first hit in key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[["a,b,c", "john"], ["d,e", "mark"], ["f", "aby"], ["g,i,j", "mary"]], schema=["keys", "name"])

+-----+----+
| keys|name|
+-----+----+
|a,b,c|john|
|  d,e|mark|
|    f| aby|
|g,i,j|mary|
+-----+----+
```

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[["b", 18], ["c", 25], ["d", 55], ["i", 90], ["j", 88]], schema=["key", "age"])

+---+---+
|key|age|
+---+---+
|  b| 18|
|  c| 25|
|  d| 55|
|  i| 90|
|  j| 88|
+---+---+
```

I would like to join them by df1.keys_array and df2.key values only on first hit, so the df3 would like like this:

```
+-----+----+----+
| keys|name| age|
+-----+----+----+
|a,b,c|john|  18|
|  d,e|mark|  55|
|    f| aby|NULL|
|g,i,j|mary|  90|
+-----+----+----+
```

I tried to create new array column, containing keys and match on that, but it joins all rows, instead of just the one with first key occurence.

```
df1 = df1.withColumn('keys_array', f.split('keys', ','))
joined_df = df1.join(df2, f.expr("array_contains(keys_array, key)"), 'left_outer').show()
+-----+----+----------+----+----+
| keys|name|keys_array| key| age|
+-----+----+----------+----+----+
|a,b,c|john| [a, b, c]|   b|  18|
|a,b,c|john| [a, b, c]|   c|  25|
|  d,e|mark|    [d, e]|   d|  55|
|    f| aby|       [f]|null|null|
|g,i,j|mary| [g, i, j]|   i|  90|
|g,i,j|mary| [g, i, j]|   j|  88|
+-----+----+----------+----+----+
```

How do I make sure only first occurrence of `key` in `keys_array` are matched?

Comment: what did you try ? what is blocking you ? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I tried using array_contains. It seems to be matching rows properly, but for all rows, and I don't know how to limit it to only first occurrence of a key match. (Edited initial post to add this information).

Comment: why not run `drop_duplicates()` on `joined_df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From where your stopped, I'd simply add a [`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) for each keys order by the position of the key in the array:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

last_df = (
    joined_df
    .withColumn("rnk", F.expr("array_position(keys_array, key)"))
    .withColumn("rnk", F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("keys").orderBy("rnk")))
    .where(F.col("rnk") == 1)
)
```

```
last_df.show()
+-----+----+----------+----+----+---+
| keys|name|keys_array| key| age|rnk|
+-----+----+----------+----+----+---+
|a,b,c|john| [a, b, c]|   b|  18|  1|
|  d,e|mark|    [d, e]|   d|  55|  1|
|    f| aby|       [f]|null|null|  1|
|g,i,j|mary| [g, i, j]|   i|  90|  1|
+-----+----+----------+----+----+---+
```